# Electrons decaying into heavier particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, pressure, electrons, pauli-exclusion-principle, leptons

Suppose we have a system of electrons a very tightly confined space (like a  tiny magnetic trap).

Let's say we continually increase the degree of confinement such that the electrons are confined into a smaller and smaller space, to the point where the degeneracy pressure reaches a scale comparable to the masses of the other charged leptons.

Does there come a point where it's favourable for an electron to "decay" into a heavier lepton due to degeneracy pressure (producing neutrinos and antineutrinos in the process)? My thought is that this process would be somewhat analogous to the formation of a neutron star (or hypothetical quark star).

What would happen if we kept confining the particles into a smaller and smaller space to increase the potential further? Would even heavier particles be produced?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but I'd just like to point out a couple issues. First you say the reason for the increased electron energy is "electric potential energy." But then later on it's "degeneracy pressure." If it's potential energy then decaying to a muon or tau doesn't help - they have the same charge but more mass. So you should be talking about degeneracy pressure the whole time, and its the fermi energy you want to be above the mass of the muon.

Comment: Second all the traps I can think of the strength of the trap will have to scale with the potential generated by the electrons. There's the magnetic mirror trap, which electrons exponentially decay out of because of cyclotron radiation, and if the electrons are colliding with each other it's even worse. There's storage rings, which I'm not expert in but I believe the strength of the magnets will have to increase with the density of the plasma. Then there's traps like the penning trap which use electrostatics, where you can only store 100MeV electrons if you have 100MV electrodes.

Comment: All good points, I'll edit the question regarding degeneracy pressure. Regarding the trap, I'm asking as a thought experiment so the trap is hypothetical in nature (I'm also interested if any contradiction arises from such a strong trap which invalidates the thought experiment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you confine the electrons such that they have a higher and higher number density then their Fermi energy will increase. The Fermi energy will first become relativistic ($ \gg$ 0.51 MeV) and ultimately may exceed the rest mass energy of a muon (105.7 MeV).

At that point it become energetically possible for "muonisation" to take place, for example:
$$ e \rightarrow \mu + \bar{\nu}_\mu + \nu_e $$
with the neutrinos escaping.

An equilibrium would then be set up where the chemical potentials of the electrons and muons were equal. If both behave as ideal fermion gases then we coould say
$$ m_\mu c^2 (1 + x_\mu^2)^{1/2} = m_e c^2 (1 + x_e^2)^{1/2}\ , $$
where $x$ is the dimensionless Fermi momentum given by
$$ x_{\mu, e} = \left(\frac{3h^3}{8\pi}\right)^{1/3} \frac{n_{\mu,e}^{1/3}}{m_{\mu, e}c}\ .$$
This equation can be solved (for example) as a function of $n_e$ to give the ratio of $n_\mu/n_e$, which will increase with $n_e$.

This is a process thought to occur in neutron star interiors but requires densities about twice that of nuclear matter. The threshold in your setup would be found by equating the electron Fermi energy to 105.7 MeV, giving muonisation beginning at $n_e \simeq 5\times 10^{42}$ m$^{-3}$.

Further complications will follow when the Fermi energies exceed the rest mass energies of pions at $\sim$ 140 MeV and then kaons at $\sim 500$ MeV and $\rho$ mesons at $\sim 770$ MeV, since these could be produced (with the appropriate neutrinos to conserve lepton numbers).

If you were to keep pushing the densities higher, then the Fermi energies of the electrons and muons (which are equal) would reach the rest mass energy of a tau lepton (1777 MeV). At that point it becomes energetically feasible to create tau leptons from electrons and muons at the highest energies in their respective Fermi distributions.

The equilibrium concentrations could then again be worked out as a function of the electron number density but I think this is considerably more complicated because of the possible decay routes into mesons. One would also have to consider whether all particles are confined equally. Presumably neutral mesons would just escape along with the neutrinos.

Note that baryonic hadrons could not be created (conservation of baryon number).

**EDIT:**

@AXensen points out that electrons cannot simply decay into a muon in the way suggested above because it is not possible to conserve both energy and momentum. I think that is correct, one either needs reactions involving *two* electrons or an electron and a neutrino: e.g.
$$ \bar{\nu}_e + e \rightarrow \bar{\nu}_\mu + \mu $$

A two-electron process would need to produce *two* muons because otherwise space would have to be found at lower energies in the electron Fermi distribution, which is strongly disfavoured.

A process involving another neutrino requires a source of those neutrinos and there is nothing obvious if your plasma consists solely of a cloud of electrons.

In more realistic (neutral) plasmas then there can also be some baryons present. If so then that opens up many possible pathways to produce neutrinos (e.g. electron capture) and then muons and heavier particles as described above (this is indeed exactly what is inferred to happen inside a neutron star).

Comment: I agree with most of this, except the proposed muonisation reaction. A single electron will not "decay" in this way. A single electron will have a momentum, and the reaction will have to preserve that momentum. So it's not possible for an electron with kinetic energy $\epsilon_F=m_\mu c^2$ to "decay" to a muon with zero momentum. The momentum would have to go to the neutrinos, which would carry away a ton of energy, making the end product have more energy. The muon production mechanism would be two electrons colliding with a center-of-mass-frame-energy greater then two muon masses.

Comment: I've also realized two other issues. First, your proposal of interacting with a neutrino, as well as any way for two electrons to produce a muon, involves one _or more_ weak vertices. So these will be extremely rare and it may be unreasonable to assume equilibrium will ever be achieved. Second, the neutrinos carry away energy (in fact, most of the energy in any reaction). I'm not quite sure how to handle that in a thermodynamic analysis. i.e. don't forget about the energy and chemical potential for neutrinos.

Comment: @AXensen I've made an edit. If indeed the trapped material consists solely of electrons then I think you are right, only a 2-electron process producing 2 muons will do. In which case the threshold will still be when $E_F \simeq m_\mu c^2$ . In more realistic plasmas, which surely contain some baryons, then there are other processes that are probably more efficient involving neutrinos (which is what happens inside neutron stars).

Comment: @AXensen the point about achieving equilibrium is fair - I have no ready way to calculate whether that is possible - but then this is a hypothetical scenario. It certainly is at the densities of neutron stars - which is what we are considering.  However, the two-electron process could be rarer still, so fair point.

Comment: @AXensen the point about the neutrino energies though I don't follow. When the electrons have just enough energy to create the muons then the neutrinos will not take away much energy. If you increase the electron energy then the created muons will always be created at the top of THEIR Fermi distribution - hence one equates the Fermi energies. The neutrino chemical potential is set to zero because their number density in the plasma will always be close to zero (e.g. p39 and p222 of Black Holes, White Dwarfs and Neutron Stars by Shapiro & Teukolsky, which deals with npe and npe$\mu$ fluids.)

Comment: Yeah you're right. good responses. In the ee->uu near threshold reaction, the neutrinos will carry away _some_ energy but not a lot. I was mistaken thinking of, for example, muon decaying to electron and neutrinos - typically the neutrinos carry away more energy. And yeah there is no neutrino chemical potential. There is an interesting thing that happens where two electrons make two muons with less total energy (because of the neutrinos), then the muons can never decay back to electrons because there are no available states for the electrons to fill.

Comment: ProfRob, would you please (briefly) relate your **EDIT** (addressing @AXensen's intervention) to the situation in [beta-plus-decay](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22beta+plus+decay%22). Obviously, a proton **can** decay to the (in a suitable sense) heavier neutron, plus leptons, **provided that** the nucleons are (and remain) suitably confined to a nucleus. ...

Comment: @user12262 I can't see the relevance to this question?

Comment: ProfRob: _"relevance [of comparing to beta-plus-decay] ?"_ -- Your **EDIT** states: $$ ~ $$
_"**electrons cannot** simply decay into a muon in the way suggested above [namely, OP: electrons [in] a very tightly confined space; and producing neutrinos and antineutrinos in the process] because it is not possible to conserve both energy and momentum"_ $$ ~ $$
However, [beta-plus-decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#%CE%B2+_decay) seems equivalent under substitution "**protons, confined to a nucleus, can and do**".
So: Which relevant distinction am I missing (that you seem to draw) ?

Comment: @user12262  for decays in a nucleus there is no problem balancing momentum and energy because the nucleus is more massive than the ejected particles. The electrons here are free particles.

Comment: ProfRob: _"[...] because the nucleus is more massive than the ejected particles.[...]"_ -- Thanks for this response; I'm trying to "digest" it ... In the OP setup, the "confining system" (magnetic trap plus electron, or muon) is also more massive than the (hypothetically) ejected neutrinos, right? So: I still fail to see a (qualitative) distinction **relevant** enough to prevent decays exactly as the OP suggested. Now, you've done and presented calculations, while I've not (yet). Did you really explicitly find that in the OP suggestion **there is a problem** balancing momentum and energy ? ...

Comment: @user122262 Consider the decay in the rest frame of the decaying particle. How can it decay into a more massive particle? If you have further Qs you could ask a new Q.

Comment: ProfRob: _"Consider decay in the rest frame of the decaying particle."_ -- Fair enough. (Though it'd be complicated, due to the immense interactions w the "trap" part of the confining system) _"How can it decay into a more massive particle?"_ -- Obvious: By the confining system as a whole transitioning to a correspondingly **even less massive state** (Exactly what you describe in your answer ahead and until your questionable **EDIT**, at least AFAIU.) _"[...] you could ask a new Q."_ -- Or I could submit precisely your A but w/o that EDIT right here, as my A. (But I'll wait a week, or two ...)

Answer (score 1):

The possibility of confining fermions (of the same kind) and in particular electrons to the Fermi energy of the system approaching and exceeding the respective fermion mass is certainly discussed in the literature, and is considered relevant in models of ["relativistic degenerate matter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_matter).

Among the "practicalities" that may thereby be considered and addressed are (foremost electromagnetic) interactions between the fermions, $(e^+ ~ e^-)$ pair production, "thermal background photons", external fields ...

> *[...] favourable for an electron to "decay" into a heavier lepton due to degeneracy pressure (producing neutrinos and antineutrinos in the process)?*

As putting the word *decay* in "scare quotes" indicates, it is understood that a plain decay
$$ e \rightarrow \mu + \bar{\nu}_\mu + \nu_e $$
cannot happen by itself; itstead we're considering state transitions of the entire confined system.

So your question, as far as I understand it, is asking whether a sufficiently confined system ${\large S}_{\left(\begin{matrix}e^- \! : ~ n \\ \mu^- \! : ~ j \end{matrix}\right)}$ of many ($n \gg 1$) "ultrarelativistic" electrons, and hardly any muons ($0 \le j \ll n$) muons may undergo a state transition with **exactly the net change of losing one electron, gaining one muon**, and producing $\bar{\nu}_\mu + \nu_e$ (which might as well escape); specificly:

$$ {\large S}_{\left(\begin{matrix}e^- \! : ~ n \\ \mu^- \! : ~ 0 \end{matrix}\right)} {\Large \rightarrow} ~~{\large S}_{\left(\begin{matrix}e^- \! : ~ n + 1 \\ \mu^- \! :   ~~~ 1 ~~~ \end{matrix}\right)}  + \bar{\nu}_\mu + \nu_e. $$

${\large \mathbf {And ~ to ~ make ~ a ~ long ~ story ~ short \! \!:}}$ ${\Large \mathbf {Yes!}}$ ${\large \mathbf { \!, ~ that's ~ possible}}$ under fairly general conditions. For instance:

1. Requiring the (very) detailed transition process
   $$ (e^- + e^-) \rightarrow \mu^- + e^- + \bar{\nu}_\mu + \nu_e $$
   such that the **momentum magnitudes** of the two initially given electrons as well as the one remaining electron **are all equal** (and at least about $105.7~{\rm MeV / c}$, wrt. the center of mass of the whole confined system) *is allowed* even at vanishing temperature if

- the initially given electrons approach each other at a suitable angle (say, $120°$, as measured wrt. the confined system),
- the muon and neutrinos are produced nearly at rest  wrt. the confined system), and
- the therefore resulting momentum of the remaining electron happened to have a suitable direction (and magnitude as prescribed) correponding to a state which just became available, since one electron of equal momentum magnitude had just been removed from the confined system (even though its momentum had a different direction).

2. Requiring more generally at finite temperature
   $$ (e^- + e^-) \rightarrow \mu^- + e^- + \bar{\nu}_\mu + \nu_e $$
   with the remaining electron having any momentum of smaller magnitude than $105.7~{\rm MeV / c}$, and with just a suitable direction of a "still" free state (which is generally available at finite temperature).
   (Then the initial momentum magnitudes may be even less than $105.7~{\rm MeV / c}$, also depending on the collision angle.)
3. By "absorbing a thermal photon":
   $$ (e^- + \gamma) \rightarrow \mu^- + \bar{\nu}_\mu + \nu_e $$
   (is allowed with electron and photon momenta as "small" as about $53~{\rm MeV / c}$).

Comment: Heads-up!, @ProfRob .